# Saving data in a JSON file with WordPress AJAX

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress, hook, file-put-contents

So I have a wordpress Ajax function that retrieves MySQL data as JSON and logs it. However I want to not directly get the data back on the page where my AJAX function is, but I want to save the data to a JSON file instead, so I can use it for a wider variety of purposes.

Here is my AJAX function:

```
$.get(
        ajax_url,
        data,
        function(data) { // AJAX callback
            fill_json(data);
        }// End AJAX callback
    );
```

The `fill_json()` is a function to echo the JSON data in a table I wrote myself.

Now here is what happens inside my AJAX hook:

```
$sql_search = $wpdb->get_results(" a complicated mysql search here ");
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $result = json_encode($result);         
        echo $result;
    } else {
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
    }
```

underneath `echo $result;` in my Ajax hook I tried the following piece of code, but I don't know how I can see if it worked or not:

```
        $json_path = "/var/www/vhosts/jtc.ae/httpdocs/pre/wp/wp-content/themes/Amazing_japan_HP/new/search.json";
        file_put_contents($json_path, $result);
```

My question:
**Is this the correct way to save the data to a JSON file, and how can I get this data on my main page then?**

Extra question: Will saving `$result` to a JSON file conflict with multiple users using the AJAX at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you did is right .. please make sure the steps below :

1. Pass write permission to the folder /new inside "Amazing_japan_HP" (chmod -R 666 /new)
2. To save the data in file use file_put_contents($file, $current);
3. To get the data from the file use $current = file_get_contents($file);
4. For all newly created files try to use [umask](http://php.net/umask). It provides required permission to the files for writing content in it

> umask() sets PHP's umask to mask & 0777 and returns the old umask.
>   When PHP is being used as a server module, the umask is restored when
>   each request is finished.

Comment: Hey Prakash, the write options are fine. I tried to get data on my main page with `$current = file_get_contents($file);` but it showed nothing. When getting json data from ajax, what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: thanks for your help. Sorry I marked it correct many years later. Your upvote on my question is much appreciated!! : D